# Should the Kaplan-Meier p-value be adjusted if new data are added?

Tags: p-value, survival, kaplan-meier, adjustment

The event of interest is subscription purchase and the time variable is days since the creation of the subscription trial within an AB Test. The stakeholders want to monitor the progress each day as both new customers are added and subscription purchases are made.

I feel that presenting the survival curves is fine with updating data, however, should there be some kind of correction for the p-value due to the multiple testing?

Or should the p-value be calculated as standard and compared to a fixed alpha determined a priori?

If the latter how would I adjust alpha appropriately?

Comment: Do you mean to ask if the alpha threshold (for determining if p is significant) should be updated? That would make more sense as you can't calculate p values a priori.

Comment: Yes, the alpha threshold, I mean. Should it be alpha/n (where n is the number of tests)?